# Eclipse Hello world fail on mac , toolchain?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Just started a beginner c++ tutorial which eclipse is used. I am using a mac, so when creating a new project i chose the toolchain 'macxxx" something. In the video a different one is used because it is done in windows.

I tried running this super easy program :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

int main() {    
    cout <<'C++ is FUN'\n;    
    return 0;    
}
```

When i click on the hammer to build it, I just get 3 errors :

> Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved   firstprogram.cpp        Semantic Error

all similar to that.
How can i fix that ?

Comment: Say, you've been doing a lot of SQL lately, haven't you? Jokes aside, C++ literals have to be enclosed in double-quotes, not in single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does following code produce errors aswell?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

You can end current line with `<< endl` after `"Some text to display"`. So it would look like

```
cout << "hello there " << endl;
```